# Doctrine syntax error with field named "order"

Tags: sql, ajax, jquery, symfony

I have the following ajax call

```
var prev_sibling = $(this).prev().attr("value");
var next_sibling = $(this).next().attr("value");
var order = (prev_sibling + next_sibling)/2; 
var data = {PID:element_id, TGID:parent_id, ORD:order};
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        url:"{{ path('v2_pm_patents_dragpatents') }}",
        cache: false
});
```

And in my action I get the order and set it like this

```
$order = $request->get('ORD');
$patent->setOrder($order);
```

but the ajax call give me thew following error

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near &#039;order = &#039;750&#039; WHERE id = &#039;0d0c0810-bc75-11e1-96a5-9787dec335c2&#039;&#039; at line 1 (500 Internal Server Error)
```

I get the post data correctly and the query which gives me these records is also working fine.

Where is the problem?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: well it's not so much the ajax call giving the error. It's a SQL problem. What does your doctrine mapping look like?

Comment: @MDrollette I think order is the reserved keyword in mysql and which is also the name of my column. I think that is the reason of the problem what do you think?

Comment: @MDrollette and now the problem is someone else created the db and i dont have the write access... so better to create an issue on redmine to change the column name first then i can give it a try n time to watch a movie now :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The problem is `order` being a reserved word in MySQL. If you are using doctrine you can tell it to escape reserved words in the mapping like so:

```
/** @Column(name="`order`", type="integer") */
private $order;
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words

Comment: it would definitely cleaner to rename it. But this should *work*

Comment: let me give it a try I will inform the concern person to rename the columns... Thanks :)

Comment: There is a Doctrine DBAL issue about this here: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-40

Comment: do not forget 
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column as Column;

Comment: I had a similar issue with a field named "set". It worked when the system was written using PostgreSQL, but converting it to use MySQL caused it to crash when trying to write to this table. Fortunately, adding the backticks worked perfectly. More surprisingly, it worked for both the databases; I was expecting it to only work for MySQL, which would have been a big problem for me, but it also worked with PostgreSQL. The real question that surprises me is why doesn't Doctrine handle this scenario transparently anyway?

Comment: link is dead, but the answer is still helpful